# How to record and play a captured video using AVAssertWriter and AVAssertReader in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avassetreader

I am displaying the camera data (video) on the preview layer.Now I want to record the video and store it in a local file and access it to play on the screen.

I had seen some websites that it is possible with `AVAssertWriter` and `AVAssertReader`. Its very difficult for me to understand. Can any one advice me in a clearcut manner or with any sample code.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Comment: Apple has sample code for all this. Also, see the WWDC videos.